# Possible causes to crash during boost::thread spawning

Tags: c++, ios, crash, exc-bad-access, boost-thread

Executing

```
`boost::thread(boost::bind(&SomeClass::someStaticFunction, someParam));`
```

sometimes causing a crash. Please notice that the function is static. The trace I see is:

```
* thread #35: tid = 0x2a822, 0x00d2469e NdsVgconnectTestApp`boost::(anonymous namespace)::thread_proxy(param=<unavailable>) + 246 at thread.cpp:164, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20000008)
  * frame #0: 0x00d2469e NdsVgconnectTestApp`boost::(anonymous namespace)::thread_proxy(param=<unavailable>) + 246 at thread.cpp:164
    frame #1: 0x3b877918 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 140
    frame #2: 0x3b87788a libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 102
```

What could be the possible reasons for the EXC_BAD_ACCESS? 
Could it happen due to too many threads or memory allocation overrun (it was 54 threads when the app crashed) ?

Comment: Is this error saying the function crashed? What's in the function? Are you just running it on one thread?

Comment: @doctorlove I'm running an application on iPad. From logs and call stack I can see that the crash occurred after the mentioned line. As I said, there were 54 threads when the crash occurred.

Comment: And all 54 threads were calling this static function (which I can't see the code for)? I suspect the `stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means you are accessing memory your shouldn't. It could be array sizes, or an initialisation problem/race condition. Hard to say from here.

Comment: The crash occurs in boost code in thread.cpp file. The working function passed to boost::thread wasn't executed yet.

Comment: @doctorlove my reply above